# How to draw a Gaussian Curve with LibreOffice Draw?

Tags: gaussian, libreoffice, libreoffice-draw

I would like to draw a Gaussian curve as a vector graphic in LibreOffice Draw. With the "Curve" functions I was only able to get something  [parabola-like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io0ok.png)
Has anyone got an idea of how to do the Gaussian?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A Gaussian curve is basically a normal distribution aka a bell curve.

This is sort of a hack.

In libre office **calc**

Add the following data in a column.

`1
2
4
5
4
2
1`

Then **insert->chart->line**
From the Dialogue box **Select line AND line only AND smooth line **
[image: Select line AND line only AND smooth line]

You should end up with a chart that looks like this.
[image: Gaussian curve / Bell curve / Normal distribution]

In libreoffice calc **double click** on the chart bell curve then **right click** on the **bell curve LINE**

[image: Libreoffice calc bell curve grab]

Then **from the menu (right click menu) select copy**

Open Libreoffice **draw** and then paste.

You should have something like this.

[image: Bell curve in libreoffice draw]

You can make your own spin.

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you said it's kind of a hack, but it's very useful one because you can create with it whatever curve you like!

Comment: Indeed @Ethunxxx All the best Libre!